# MvvmCross.Plugins.File: A Downloaded and locally stored image is not displayed in MvxImageView

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I save an image from the internet like this:

```
public void SetSelectedConsultant(string consultantId)
{
    // ...

    var path = this.fileStore.PathCombine(App.IMAGES_FOLDER, App.SELECTED_CONSULTANT_IMAGE_FILENAME);

    if (this.fileStore.Exists(path))
    {
        this.fileStore.DeleteFile(path);
    }

    this.fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(App.IMAGES_FOLDER);

    this.GeneralAsyncLoad(
        App.SERVER_URL + App.CONSULTANT_FILE_NAME,
        stream =>
            {
                this.SaveConsultantImage(stream, path);
                this.mvxMessenger.Publish(new ConsultantUpdatedMessage(this));
            });
}

private void SaveConsultantImage(Stream stream, string path)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] pictureBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    this.fileStore.WriteFile(path, pictureBytes);
}
```

`ConsultantUpdatedMessage` is caught by my view model which will RaisePropertyChanged for `ConsultantImageUrl`. My other properties like ConsultantName etc. are refreshed correctly in the view, but the image refuses to show in the control:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ConsultantImageUrl" />
```

I checked if the file exists, usin fileStore.Exists, which results "true", but the file won't show up. Is it possible I save the picture the wrong way?

**EDIT**: As a how-to, I used this tutorial (https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-16-CollectABull-Part5). However, there they use a photo from the local album instead of downloading one.

Comment: Could you add some more code for how ConsultantImageUrl in the view model is being used?  Do you see anything weird in the debug trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The url was wrong and it downloaded another (none-image) file and saved it. So a file was existing there, but could not be displayed in the view because it was not an image.